# How to do Alert dialog in Android Kotlin return boolean value

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-alertdialog, alert

I want to make static function with Alert dialog which return boolean value.

In C# it looks like:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //do something
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
    //do something else
}
```

In Kotlin i have class with companion object

```
class Dialog {
    companion object {
        fun question(context: Context, title: String, message: String) {
            AlertDialog.Builder(context).apply {
                setIcon(R.drawable.ic_question)
                setTitle(title)
                setMessage(message)
                setPositiveButton("YES", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                })
                setNegativeButton("NO", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                })
            }.show()

        }
    }
}
```

And i want to return Boolean result from question function.

I want to use this function in my activity like this:

```
if(Dialog.question(this,"Title", "Message")) {
    //something
} else {
    //something
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

What you need:

- Extend your Dialog.kt class with DialogFragment()
- Create an interface for your activity in the dialog class
- Define a function which is called when the dialog closes
- Override the dialog interface to make what you need
- Use your interface

This is the implementation in my code (tested and working)

---

Implementation:

Extend your Dialog.kt class with DialogFragment, adapt your code to this and create the interface

```
class Dialog: DialogFragment() {
    interface InputListener {
        fun sendBoolean(value: Boolean)
    }
    ...
}
```

In the positive / negative listeners lambdas, init your interface and send the boolean

```
val inputListener = activity as InputListener
inputListener.sendInput(YOUR_VALUE)
dialog?.dismiss()
```

Go to your activity and extend it with your interface

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(), Dialog.InputListener {
   ...
}
```

And now finally, override the interface in the activity to run the code you need

```
override fun sendInput(value: Boolean) {
    if (value) {
        // Positive - true
    } else {
        // Negative - false
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this solved your problem, if not, try updating your question with what's wrong and I'll help you by updating my answer, happy coding!

Comment: thanks. It's not as pretty as I'd like, but it works for a simple example.

Comment: what if i need two questions in one activity and different action for each of them

Comment: You can create multiple intefaces with differents behaviours @marios160