# How to execute a function in an activity when a button in a dialog is pressed

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

[FriendDialog.kt]

```
binding.addFriendBtn.setOnClickListener{}
```

[SearchPeopleActivity]

```
Thread{
    fun setFriend() {
        try {
            val userName = getName()
            val friendName = getFriendName()

            val jsonObject = JSONObject() //json 초기화
            jsonObject.put("user_name", userName)
            jsonObject.put("friend", friendName)
            Request().reqpost("http://dmumars.kro.kr/api/setfriend", jsonObject)

        } catch (e: UnknownServiceException) {
            println(e.message)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    setFriend()
}.start()
```

I want use uuid for finding my App user. So I use SearchPeopleActivity and Dialog for when I find another user and click dialog button to send another user for friend request.

But when I get uuid and use it only in SerchPeopleActivity.kt. So I tried to solve this problem with intent but I can't get user uuid and get error I can't find user. and  ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2
error...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RQiQ.png)

I want use this Thread when I click add_friend_btn in FriendDialog.kt

My FriendDialog.kt code is this

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import com.example.marsproject.databinding.ActivityFriendDialogBinding

class FriendDialog(id: String) : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityFriendDialogBinding

    private var id: String? = null

    init {
        this.id = id
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = ActivityFriendDialogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

        binding.addFriendBtn.setOnClickListener{
        }

        binding.finishBtn.setOnClickListener{
            dismiss()
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

and my SearchPeopleActivity.kt code is here.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.view.animation.Animation
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import com.example.marsproject.databinding.ActivityFriendDialogBinding
import com.example.marsproject.databinding.ActivitySearchPeopleBinding
import com.kakao.sdk.user.UserApiClient
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.w3c.dom.Text
import java.net.UnknownServiceException
import kotlin.random.Random

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
class SearchPeopleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySearchPeopleBinding
    private lateinit var bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager
    private lateinit var bluetoothsearch: BluetoothSearch

    private lateinit var statusTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var findUser: ImageView
    private lateinit var fadeInAnimation: Animation
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySearchPeopleBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

    
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar) 
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) 
        supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_left_resize) 
        supportActionBar?.title = "Find Friend Around you" 

        bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothsearch = BluetoothSearch(bluetoothManager)

        statusTextView = binding.searchingText
        fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in)

        statusTextView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation)

        statusTextView.visibility = TextView.VISIBLE




        if (!bluetoothsearch.bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
           
            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            resultLaunch.launch(enableBtIntent) 
        } else {
           
            if (bluetoothsearch.startbluetoothSearch(bluetoothSearchCallback, 2)) {
            }
        }
    }

    
    val resultLaunch = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
       
        if (result.resultCode == -1) {
           
            if (bluetoothsearch.startbluetoothSearch(bluetoothSearchCallback, 2)) {
                statusTextView = binding.searchingText
                fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in)

                
                statusTextView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation)
                statusTextView.visibility = TextView.VISIBLE

            }
        }
    }

    val bluetoothSearchCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        private val isdup = ArrayList<String>() 

       
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)

            /*val devicename = result?.device?.name
            val devicemac = result?.device?.address*/
            val deviceuuid = result?.scanRecord?.serviceUuids?.get(0)


            fun getFriendName(): String{
                var FriendName = ""
                try {
                   
                    val jsonObject =
                        Request().reqget("http://dmumars.kro.kr/api/getbtuserdata/${deviceuuid}")

                    
                    FriendName = jsonObject.getString("user_name")
                } catch (e: UnknownServiceException) {
                    Log.d("bluetooth", "this uuid user is not in our App")
                }
                return FriendName
            }

            Thread{
                runOnUiThread {
                    findUser = binding.friend1
                    findUser.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation) 

                    val screenWidth = 409
                    val screenHeight = 673

                    val randomX = (0..screenWidth).random()
                    val randomY = (0..screenHeight).random()

                    findUser.x = randomX.toFloat()
                    findUser.y = randomY.toFloat()

                    findUser.visibility = ImageView.VISIBLE

                    findUser.setOnClickListener{
                        UserApiClient.instance.me { user, error ->
                            if(user != null){

                                val dialog = FriendDialog("${user.id}")
                         
                                dialog.isCancelable = false
                                dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "FriendDialog")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            val btnId = intent.getIntExtra("friend",R.id.add_friend_btn)
                if(btnId == R.id.add_friend_btn){
                    Thread{
                        fun setFriend() {
                            try {
                                val userName = getName()
                                val friendName = getFriendName()

                                val jsonObject = JSONObject() 
                                jsonObject.put("user_name", userName)
                                jsonObject.put("friend", friendName)
                                Request().reqpost("http://dmumars.kro.kr/api/setfriend", jsonObject)

                            } catch (e: UnknownServiceException) {
                                println(e.message)
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        }
                        setFriend()
                    }.start()
                }
        }
    }

    fun getName(): String {
        val pref = getSharedPreferences("userName", 0)
        return pref.getString("name", "").toString()
    }


    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item?.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> { 
                bluetoothsearch.stopbluetoothSearch(bluetoothSearchCallback)
                finish() 
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76371800/14120486) may not fit perfectly to your question but I think you can use it to solve your problem.